# Как найти количество малых латинских букв?

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции, текст

Задание:

1. Ввести символьный массив из 9 элементов .
2. Найти количество малых латинских букв в заданном массиве.

У меня проблема со второй частью задания.     Подскажите как мне найти количество малых букв.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно пойти от противного и убрать из строки все не латинские буквы в нижнем регистре, а после подсчитать длину строки:

```
import re
text = re.sub('[^a-z]', '', 'HElow23orld!')
print(text)  # 'loworld'
print(len(text))  # 7
```

---

**adrug** правильно заметил, что если через регулярки делать, то можно использовать метод `findall`:

```
import re
print(len(re.findall('[a-z]', 'HElow23orld!')))  # 7
```

---

Или можно перебрать список символов и оставить только нужные, а после подсчитать:

```
import string
print(len([c for c in 'HElow23orld!' if c in string.ascii_lowercase]))
```

---

**mkkik**, подсказал реализацию в стиле функционального программирования:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
print(len(tuple(filter(ascii_lowercase.count, 'HElow23orld!'))))
```

добавлю еще вариант, магический метод `__contains__`, который вызывается оператором `in`:

```
print(len(list(filter(ascii_lowercase.__contains__, 'HElow23orld!'))))
```

Comment: Почему бы не сделать findall на [a-z] и потом результат сделать len?

Comment: Может, последний вариант будет компактнее с фильтом `len(tuple(filter(ascii_lowercase.count, 'HElow23orld!')))`, если не затрагивать вопросы производительности.

Comment: @adrug, добавил

Comment: @mkkik, добавил

Answer (score 5):

можно найти сумму истинных значений (внутреннее представление `True` в Python - это `1`), проверяя принадлежат ли символы диапазону `a-z`:

```
In [8]: s = 'HElow23orld!'

In [9]: print(sum(97 <= ord(x) <= 122 for x in s))
7
```

или

```
In [18]: print(sum(ord('a') <= ord(x) <= ord('z') for x in s))
7
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант:

```py
s = 'HElow23orld!'
print(len(list(filter(str.islower, s)))) 

# 7
```

или

```py
s = 'HElow23orld!'
print(sum(map(str.islower, s))) 

# 7
```

`str.islower` - в данном случае, учитывает все строчные буквы, в том числе и русского алфавита.
Если требуются только латинские строчные буквы, то используется другая функция для проверки вхождения символа в латинский алфавит:

```py
import string

s = 'HElow23orld! а, и, б сидели на трубе...'
print(sum(map(lambda x: x in string.ascii_lowercase, s))) 
# 7

print(sum(map(lambda x: 'a' <= x <= 'z' , s)))
# 7
```