# Подсчёт малых латинских букв в массиве

Tags: python

1.Массив в который нужно будет ввести из клавиатуры значение  из 9-ти элементов  (например hGjs8$g*1)

2.Для элементов в данном массиве ,определить есть ли там малые латинские буквы

3.Если есть вывести их количество

Проблема со второй частью программы

Мой вариант :

```
    S=[input  ()]
    k=0
    for i in S:
        if (i in [a-z]):
            k=k+1
    print (k)
```

Comment: Тут уже есть решение вашего вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/831500/201445

Comment: Студенты одного препода,одни и те же вопросы xd

Answer (score 0):

```
S=input()
k=0
for i in S:
    if i.islower():
        k=k+1
print (k)
```

Или так, если вы хотите чтобы S - была типа list

```
S=[input()]
k=0
for i in S[0]:
    if i.islower():
        k=k+1
print (k)
```

Comment: Если будут введены буквы другого языка, например русского, то ваш алгоритм их тоже подсчитает. Кроме того, ваш код немного избыточен, хватит: `print(len([c for c in input() if c.islower()]))` или другой вариант с подсчетом через сумму: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/831603/201445

Comment: Можно проще, через вхождение в string.ascii_lowercase